# Notation for the regular and the adjoint representation of a finite group, in particular the symmetric group

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, notation

The (left) regular representation of a finite group $G$ is the action on itself by left multiplication, $g\cdot h = gh$.

The adjoint representation of a finite group $G$ is the action on itself by conjugation, $g\cdot h = g h g^{-1}$.

> Question: I am looking for good (or traditional) notation for these two actions, mostly for the symmetric group $\mathfrak S_n$.

For a Lie group $G$, I believe it is common to denote the adjoint representation by $\mathfrak g$, because in this case $G$ acts on its Lie algebra.

From the point of view of combinatorial species, the regular representation of the symmetric group on $n$ letters might be denoted by $X^n$, where $X$ is the singleton species.  The species corresponding to the action on the cosets $\mathfrak S_n/H$ of the symmetric group may then be denoted $X^n/H$.  For example, the species of oriented cycles is $X^n/\langle(1,\dots,n)\rangle$.

I am thus inclined not to use $\mathfrak S_n$ to denote the adjoint representation, but I'm not sure whether $\mathfrak s_n$ would be any better.

Comment: "For a Lie group $G$, I believe it is common to denote the adjoint representation by $\mathfrak g$, because in this case $G$ acts on its Lie algebra." There is also an adjoint action on $G$ itself (and thus a representation on the group ring of $G$). The Lie algebra isn't really topical here.

Comment: I agree, I should have just stressed the fact that a representation is often denoted by the vector space it acts on, and in the case of the adjoint action on a Lie algebra, this seems to be quite non-ambiguous.

Comment: If $\mathbb{C}G$ is the regular representation, $^{\mathrm{ad}}\mathbb{C}G$ is reasonable notation for the adjoint action.

Comment: If you're using $X^n$ for the regular representation then you might use $S_n$ for the adjoint representation, since this is the standard species notation  (called the species of "permutations"). Of course this could be confused with the use of $S_n$ for the symmetric group. (But you're probably not really going to use $X^n$ for the regular representation.)